# Can I use WCF for communicating (sending message) between 2 windows service?

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services, messaging

Can I use WCF for communicating between 2 windows service? If yes, How?

Comment: Yes - each Windows service will need to be a client to the other service's WCF endpoint

Comment: Yes you can, but please elaborate scenario, do you want to share the state or pass data from one service to another?

Comment: I want to call a method from each other and get the answer.

Comment: If your WCF service runs in same machine as the windows services, your could use 2 way HTTP binding or TCP/IP would be better with callback to another service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure; you'd usually define a service contract (interface) which the two services will use to exchange messages; then one of the windows services would host a WCF service (in this case, where the two services are in the same machine, you'd usually use a local-only binding, such as named pipes). Then the second win service can act as a client for the WCF service on the other windows services. Is there any specific issue you're facing?

Comment: I want to call a method from each other and get the answer.

Comment: You can have one WCF service per windows service, as suggested in other answers.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the type of message you want to transfer. There is a lot of possible solutions:

- MSMQ messages
- Duplex contracts
- Named pipes

Basically you need to setup a WCF service on each windows service. You can use the WCF 4.0 discovery features to dynamically find the each service.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, It is possible. You can use ServiceHost class to host a WCF service in a windows service without dependency to IIS.